# Qt 4.7 QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo : No Such file or Directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtserialport

I am using **Qt 4.7.4** and **Qt Creator 2.4.1**.
I am trying to build blockingmaster code for serial communication, example given on Qt site.

But after required modification for my environment and path destination, when I tried to build the project. It gives me:

```
QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo: No such file or directory
```

After following [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort) link (with no success);

My .pro file looks like:

```
CONFIG += serialport
QT += widgets

TARGET = blockingmaster
TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += \
    dialog.h \
    masterthread.h

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    dialog.cpp \
    masterthread.cpp
```

But the error remains the same. I have tried the things upsite down.

Serial communication via QT is a new task for me, so I was trying with example given on Qt website. Can anyone provide me more information to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to all for their valuable suggestions.

**QtSerialPort library is an added feature for Qt5 .It is always advisable to use inbuilt library created by qt.**

**Since QtSerialPort library is not supported by Qt 4.7 or lower version.**

I was able to design an Application using Qt 4.7 itself. It needs to include library for serial communication as Qt 4.7 has no in-build library for serial port. I did it using following link :

For Windows add the "qextserialport-1.2rc" (download using following link)

[Qextserialport Example - Hyperterminal Windows](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-your-arduino-from-your-PC-with-the-Qt-Gui/step2/Installation-of-the-library/)

For Linux add library "myser1.zip" (download using following link)

[Qextserialport Example - Hyperterminal Linux](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32830-HowTo-use-QextSerialPort-classes)

Above links also includes the application for Serial Communication for respective OS. Adding the libraries from the above application helped me designing an Application for my task.

**The above answer will help the developers who are not permissible to upgrade Qt-tool due to company policy etc.**

Hope this will help others to solve the similar problems.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I understand that this answer is misleading, but Since QtSerialPort is not supported by Qt 4.7 version. I was left with no choice. As per the company policy, I cannot upgrade to the latest version of Qt. So I guess, the person struggling with the same issue, can resolve it using above answer.

Comment: We do support QtSerialPort with 4.7

Comment: @LaszloPapp, is it really possible ? I tried alot but always ended with an error messages. If it is so, then i would definitely upgrade my application with it. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Well, it is hard to tell without concrete errors, but yes, it is meant to work.

Comment: have you tried upgrading, and changing the answer here for the official recommendation from the Qt Project?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I need to upgrade my Qt-tool inorder to use QtSerialPort library. Which is not permissible in my Company ? I guess this answer will help the developers facing similar upgrading issue from there company. All my machine applications are designed and well tested on Qt 4.7. Its a risky as well as time consuming to move our complete project to Qt latest. As again we have to start with testing etc. But for our next Project we will definitely try to upgrade our Qt-tool to get richer functions and supports. Thanks alot for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try 4.8?

It should work with that, but try first without Qt Creator, and then if it works, with the IDE.

We have not tested 4.7 lately, hence there might be issues. 4.8 should work. If something does not, we need to find the root cause, file a bugreport, and we will fix it.

[Here](http://lpapp.blogspot.ie/2013/02/qtserialport-in-qt-51.html) you can find more information about this module that I wrote up when it was becoming an official Qt add-on.

Comment: thanks for ur comment. Some people have uploaded the libraries on Qt forums. That helped me achieving my goal. I have added the links i used in my answer.

Comment: @skg: you are mixing qextserialport and qserialport.

Answer (score 1):

The example you're looking at is for Qt 5 (probably even 5.1), it won't work with Qt 4. Try the latest 5.1 release candidate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort link shows how to use the same example for Qt 4. Also for some reasons, i cannot switch to latest version

Comment: Yes, our module should work with Qt 4. We have been puting a relative fair amount of effort to make sure it works. It should even work with Qt 4 for Android through the necessitas project. :-)